# Push notification in PHP, should I use CURL or stream_context_create()?

Tags: php, curl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to set up a push notification server. I've decided not to use node.js but php since the rest of my server logic is dev with PHP.

I've been looking around and basically I can see 2 ways to do it.

One with CURL:

- https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017
- http://gonzalo123.com/2013/08/05/sending-android-push-notifications-from-php-to-phonegap-applications/
- https://www.parse.com/questions/php-rest-example-of-targeted-push
- http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/
- http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/

THe other one with Stream_context:

- http://vxtindia.com/blog/push-notifications-for-your-iphone-app-with-php-and-ubuntu/
- https://gist.github.com/samvermette/759564
- http://iosapplove.com/archive/2013/01/apns-tutorial-how-to-send-pushnotifications-to-my-iphone-ipad-app-part-2/
- https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/

What is the difference and advantages of one method over another ?
Is there any special configuration with stream_context? more reliable ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can't send an Apple Push Notification with CURL. As you can see in all the CURL examples in your links, they are all Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) for Android examples.
>
> CURL works with GCM because GCM server accepts HTTPS requests. Apple Push Notifications, on the other hand, don't work with HTTP. They only work with a specific binary format over TCP protocol.
>
> As a provider you communicate with Apple Push Notification service over a binary interface. This interface is a high-speed, high-capacity interface for providers; it uses a streaming TCP socket design in conjunction with binary content. The binary interface is asynchronous
>
> Therefore you should use stream_context.

While this answer was true at its time, it is now outdated. Like @andreszs said, **you now CAN  use PHP/CURL to send HTTP/2 requests to APNs**.

And it's true, it is a bit of a pain to setup CURL with HTTP/2 support, as you need to compile it yourself with a couple of other libraries (like openssl and nghttp2). If you are like me and are trying to do it on Windows but don't know how to, you might want to look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46981784/how-do-i-compile-curl-with-openssl-and-nghttp2-on-windows-x64) (the process I went through to get it working).

Comment: They do work with CURL + HTTPS with a new API now, as long as you manage the miracle of making valid HTTP2 requests.