# how do I compile cURL with openSSL and nghttp2 on Windows x64?

Tags: windows, curl, openssl, xampp, http2

first question ever on here, so bear with me :) I've been on the web for the past 3 days trying to find a way to get the following result on my windows machine.

[example of 'cURL -V' output I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjAiZ.png)

I've found a lot of stuff for macOS and unix, but only bits and pieces for Windows. I'm running xampp, and ultimately I'm trying to get it to send http/2 requests through cURL/PHP. What I've gathered so far is that I need cURL to be compiled with some libraries, like openssl (at least 1.0.2), libcurl with http/2 enabled, and nghttp2. I feel like I'm very close but I'm just missing some steps.

What I've done so far:

- installed things like mingw32, cmake, and Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017
- downloaded nghttp2-1.27.0, and used 'cmake' and 'cmake --build' to get the 5 files: nghttp2.dll, .exp, .lik, .lib, and .pdb
- downloaded curl-7.56.1.tar.gz (the very first one on https://curl.haxx.se/download.html)
- downloaded libssh2-1.8.0
- downloaded openssl-1.0.2l
- downloaded zlib-1.2.11
- followed instructions for Mingw32 on https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html (but it keeps giving me the error 'cannot find openSSL package')
- I read somewhere that I need to compile cURL with the '--with-nghttp2 --prefix-[LOCATION OF NGHTTP2 FOLDER HERE]' flag, so I tried something that I thought would work, but I don't think it did: 'cmake --with-nghttp2 --prefix-[LOCATION OF NGHTTP2 FOLDER HERE] . ', then 'cmake install . ' and it looked like it did something, but the cURL.exe that was built inside curl-7.56.1/src/ did not have anything else but libcurl.

Any suggestions or pointers will be greatly appreciated! Thank you guys :)

Comment: I'd recommend using the build files in curl's `winbuild/` directory.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get somewhat forward. These are the steps I've taken: (1) downloaded `curl-7.56.1.tar.gz` and extracted it
(2) created a "deps" folder inside the `curl-7.56.1` folder
(3) downloaded `zlib1.dll`, `libssh2.dll`, and `ssleay32.dll` + `libeay32.dll`
(4) moved these four  `.dll`'s in `curl-7.56.1/deps`
(5) opened Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 (the one thing I had the could run `nmake`)
(6) `cd curl-7.56.1/winbuild`
(7) `nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=dll WITH_SSL=ssleay32.dll WITH_NGHTTP2=nghttp2.dll WITH_ZLIB=zlib1.dll WITH_SSH2=libssh2.dll`

Comment: This created a bunch of folders in `curl-7.56.1/bin`. It actually made a curl.exe but it's like it didn't take into account the `.dll`s. I tried removing the `WITH_xxx` flags, and it  built a win_ssl version of curl in a new folder inside `/bin`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I was finally able to build Curl on Windows with http/2 support.
This is what worked for me, step by step:

- Downloaded "[Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017)" to be able to build from the command line (provides `nmake` and required Windows SDK libraries and header filtes)
- downloaded the latest version of curl, like stated above (`curl-7.56.1.tar.gz`, aka for me the very first one on https://curl.haxx.se/download.html)
- extracted it inside `c:/curl`, so I ended up with `c:/curl/curl-7.56.1`
- read instructions **BUILD.WINDOWS.txt** inside `c:/curl/curl-7.56.1/winbuild` and proceeded to http://windows.php.net/downloads/php-sdk/deps/ to download the 4 libraries that I needed. I just grabbed the VC15/x86 versions.
- created a new folder named "deps" inside `c:/curl/curl-7.56.1`
- created the following 3 folders inside `c:/curl/curl-7.56.1/deps`: `bin`, `lib`, and `include`
- extracted each library I just downloaded in the corresponding 3 folders
- opened Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017
- `cd c:/curl/curl-7.56.1/winbuild`
- `nmake -f Makefile.vc mode=dll WITH_DEVEL=c:/curl/curl-7.56.1/deps WITH_SSL=dll WITH_NGHTTP2=dll WITH_ZLIB=static WITH_SSH2=dll`
- this builds a CURL executable inside one of the subfolders in `c:\curl\curl-7.56.1\builds`
- when I first tried running CURL, it showed an error saying missing **libssl-1_1.dll** and **libcrypto-1_1.dll**, so I had to copy them from `c:\curl\curl-7.56.1\deps\bin` to the same directory where the newly built **curl.exe** is
- Note: since zlib didn't come with a `bin` folder containing any `.dll`'s, I understand why I had to mark zlib as static with the `WITH_ZLIB=static` flag. What I don't get is why I had to *manually* move the openssl `.dll`'s in the new directory. Any thoughts?

PS: thank you Daniel for pointing me in the right direction. I didn't even notice the `/winbuild` directory.

PPS: As you can probably tell, I had no idea what I've been doing 90% of the time. Probably why it took me 5 days to figure it out ;)

Comment: The reason you had to copy the dll file is because Windows doesn't have `rpath`, so the DLL should be wither on the same folder with the executable or on the DLL lookup path.

Comment: Where did you get `nghttp2.dll` from? You're specifying to link it dynamically but I've not been able to build nghttp2 on Windows at all.